# Do we have $E[X|X>Y]=E[X]$ if $X$ and $Y$ are two independent continuous random variables?

Tags: probability-theory

Do we have $E[X]=E[X|X>Y]$ (1) if $X$ and $Y$ are two independent, continuous random variables?

Usually I only deal with conditioning like $X=a_i$ in the case of discrete distributions, so I am confused with this conditional expectation. My idea is, using Law of Total Expectation:

$$E[X]=Pr(X>Y)E[X|X>Y]+Pr(X\le Y)E[X|X\le Y]$$
So if (1) is true, then the above also holds. But the reverse is not necessarily true.

Comment: Unless I am mistaken, take $X$ and $Y$ to be two independent random variables on $[0,1]$, both with the uniform distribution. Then $E[X|X > Y] = \int_0^1 x^2 dx / \int_0^1 x dx = 2/3$, while $E[X] = 1/2$.

Comment: May I ask how you calculated $E[X|X>Y]$ in your example?

Comment: The region $X > Y$ in my example corresponds to the region bounded by the $X$-axis, the $Y = 1$ line and the $Y = X$ line (strictly below the $Y = X$ line, though this will not matter in this case). So the non-normalized pdf of $X|X > Y$ is $\tilde{f}(X=x | X > Y) = \int_0^x dx = x$. But a pdf needs to have total area $1$, so the normalized pdf of $(X| X > Y)$ is $f(X=x| X > Y) = 2x$. Hence $E[X|X>Y] = \int_0^1 2x^2 dx = 2/3$.